# Issue with Babel configuration/inconsistency

Tags: babeljs

In the beginning of the docs ["What is Babel"](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/), an example is listed to explain what Babel does. It states that Babel transforms the following ES2015 input:

```
[1, 2, 3].map((n) => n + 1);
```

To the following ES5 equivalent:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function(n) {
  return n + 1;
});
```

However, if you enter the same ES2015 code on the [home page widget](https://babeljs.io/) you get the following output:

```
"use strict";

[1, 2, 3].map(n => n + 1);
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the output be ES5 code?

The reason I am asking is that, after installing all the relevant packages ("@babel/cli", "@babel/core", and "@babel/preset-env") and running Babel from the command line, I am getting the same output as the home page widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work in the Babel command line. I needed to use the --presets option:

```
npx babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js --presets=@babel/preset-env
```

I still don't know why the home page widget does not work though.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your options on the babel try page.
[image]

looks
[image]

the same output ES6 entry
[image]

You should try to create a babel.config.js file to run babel without parameters

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

On this file you can config many options, for example, the presets you want to use. here more information [Babel config files](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files)

Comment: But I want to run Babel from the command line with command line options. The code in my answer works.